# getting position (x,y) , width and lenght of Lotus Notes window in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, lotus-notes

I'm trying to get the starting position (x,y), the width and the lenght of a Lotus Notes application window from a vb.net application.

so far, I've tried using `Process` to do the trick but I can't figure out what to use after finding the good process in windows running process list. The only "usefull" thing which use or see the UI is the `Process.MainWindowTitle`. It does give the title of my Notes Window but As I said, I want coordonates, width and lenght.

I also tried using back-end classes: COM object `lotus` and `domino`
But nothing in those have necessary stuff to fill my needs.

I would also need the state of the window, something like

`SHOWNORMAL`

`HIDE`

`RESTORE`

`SHOWMAXIMIZED`

`SHOWMINIMIZED`

...

**EDIT**

I want to get the position of the window to modify the position of my application. Also I want to resise and modify the position of the Notes client. My goal here is to make both of my application and the Notes client fit in the screen.

Any help is very apreaciated!

Comment: Why don't you explain what you actually are trying to do?
Normally there is no need to get the position of the Notes client from VB. If you want to manipulate the data in a Notes database, use the backend classes and don't even invoke the client.

Comment: I want to get the position of the window to modify the position of my application. Also I want to resise and modify the position of the Notes client. My goal here is to make both of my application and the Notes client fit in the screen.

Comment: Why not manipulate the data in teh backend and not even show the Notes client?
You still haven't explained what you are actually trying to do. I think that you are on the wrong track, you should work with the backend classes instead...

Answer (score 0):

I did something like that using the Windows API some years ago. Right now, I got no examples about that, but what I did it was this: get the handler from Lotus Notes window, and then, get the handler from an embedded view, and simulate a click event to set the focus in it.

You can use the WinAPI, but that's not necessarily the best approach. You should consider other alternatives as Karl-Henry Martinsson says.